# What's wrong with this example ANTLR 3 Python grammar?

Tags: python, antlr, antlr3

I'm trying to learn to use ANTLR, and seem to have come across an error while following this "tutorial": 
https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Five+minute+introduction+to+ANTLR+3

Essentially, I create the file SimpleCalc.g:

```
grammar SimpleCalc;
 
options {
    language = Python;
}
 
tokens {
    PLUS    = '+' ;
    MINUS   = '-' ;
    MULT    = '*' ;
    DIV = '/' ;
}
 
@header {
import sys
import traceback
 
from SimpleCalcLexer import SimpleCalcLexer
}
 
@main {
def main(argv, otherArg=None):
  char_stream = ANTLRFileStream(sys.argv[1])
  lexer = SimpleCalcLexer(char_stream)
  tokens = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
  parser = SimpleCalcParser(tokens);
 
  try:
        parser.expr()
  except RecognitionException:
    traceback.print_stack()
}
 
/*------------------------------------------------------------------
 * PARSER RULES
 *------------------------------------------------------------------*/
 
expr    : term ( ( PLUS | MINUS )  term )* ;
 
term    : factor ( ( MULT | DIV ) factor )* ;
 
factor  : NUMBER ;
 
 
/*------------------------------------------------------------------
 * LEXER RULES
 *------------------------------------------------------------------*/
 
NUMBER  : (DIGIT)+ ;
 
WHITESPACE : ( '\t' | ' ' | '\r' | '\n'| '\u000C' )+    { $channel = HIDDEN; } ;
 
fragment DIGIT  : '0'..'9' ;
```

When I run the ANTLR tools

```
 java -classpath antlr-3.1.3.jar antlr.Tool SimpleCalc.g
```

I receive errors, starting with the first line:

```
ANTLR Parser Generator   Version 2.7.7 (20060906)   1989-2005
SimpleCalc.g:2:1: unexpected token: grammar
error: Token stream error reading grammar(s):
SimpleCalc.g:15:1: unexpected char: '@'
SimpleCalc.g:2:1: rule grammar trapped:
SimpleCalc.g:2:1: unexpected token: grammar
TokenStreamException: unexpected char: '@'
```

This leads me to believe that I'm doing something stupid, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: The Antlr class is `org.antlr.Tool`, though that has to be a copy/paste error since it wouldn't even start with that error.

Comment: The error message points to line 2 -- what is on line 1 of the input grammar?  You haven't shown everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong `Tool` class to generate the lexer and parser. Most ANTLR 3.x versions still have dependencies with the older v2.7 version, which is therefor included in v3.x. The `Tool` class from v2.7 is called `antlr.Tool`, while the v3.x version is called `org.antlr.Tool`. The latter is the one you should be using:

```
java -classpath antlr-3.1.3.jar org.antlr.Tool SimpleCalc.g
```

### EDIT

Here's a little demo based on the grammar from the Wiki, but then with a bit of Python code added to it that evaluates the expression:

```
grammar SimpleCalc;

options {
  language=Python;
}

@header {
import sys
import traceback

from SimpleCalcLexer import SimpleCalcLexer
}

@main {
def main(argv, otherArg=None):
  char_stream = ANTLRStringStream(sys.argv[1])
  lexer = SimpleCalcLexer(char_stream)
  tokens = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
  parser = SimpleCalcParser(tokens);

  try:
    print parser.eval()
  except RecognitionException:
    traceback.print_stack()
}

eval returns [value]
 : add EOF {$value = $add.value}
 ;

add returns [value]
 : m1=mult {$value = $m1.value} ( '+' m2=mult {$value += $m2.value}
                                | '-' m2=mult {$value -= $m2.value}
                                )* 
 ;

mult returns [value]
 : a1=atom {$value = $a1.value} ( '*' a2=atom {$value *= $a2.value}
                                | '/' a2=atom {$value /= $a2.value}
                                )* 
 ;

atom returns [value]
 : NUMBER      {$value = float($NUMBER.text)}
 | '(' add ')' {$value = $add.value}
 ;

NUMBER         : DIGIT+ ('.' DIGIT*)?;
WHITESPACE     : ('\t' | ' ' | '\r' | '\n')+ {$channel = HIDDEN;};
fragment DIGIT : '0'..'9' ;
```

Generating a lexer/parser and evaluating an expression:

```
java -cp antlr-3.1.3.jar org.antlr.Tool SimpleCalc.g
python SimpleCalcParser.py "5 * (8 + 2)"
```

produces the output:

```
50.0
```

Comment: Silly me. I had assumed that the ANTLR 3 Jar didn't have ANTLR 2 bundled with it.